# Rocketheme template Ionosphere Fusion menu Subtext not working

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu-parameters

I have migrated my website from Joomla 2.5 to Joomla 3.4.8. I am using Rocketheme template and menu type is Fusion menu and want to show sub-text below some menus. But it is not working after the update. The split menu option is working absolutely fine but fusion menu is not displaying the subtext.

Although this was working fine in Joomla 2.5

Kindly, guide

Comment: have you tried adding sub text by using `//` ??

Comment: @RishiVishwakarma No I didn't try this. I want to show subtext using the Fusion Menu option. I figured out the issue recently and i.e basically coming from "JParameter" defined in lmod_roknavmenu/themes/gantry-fusion/layout.php `$item_params = new JParameter($item->getParams());` For Joomla3x I replaced the `JParameter` with `JRegistry` but now the paramter values are coming null

Comment: `JParameter`....they're still using this? I'd probably contact them about the module so they can release an update

Comment: @Lodder No they are not using it. As I have mentioned I migrated my Joomla 2.5 website to Joomla3x. Therefore, this issue has arisen. My issue is now why the JRegistry is giving me an empty value although the subtext has a value.

Comment: @Ruchika - See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12596630/getting-error-while-using-new-jparameterplugin-params-in-joomla-3-0

Comment: @Lodder Thank you :) It worked. I was missing the `loadString()` method . I only replaced the JParameter to `JRegistry`.